# CodeIgniter - Save HTML content of WYSIWYG editor in a database to be used at a later date

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, wysiwyg

This may be a longshot but I am struggling to find help online and I am genuinely lost ..

I am building a CodeIgniter Web App where users can sign in, and create email templates, then send them to contacts..

I am using the [Trumbowyg Editor](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) for creating the email templates which I have found quite good and flexible, i have pre-made templates the users can select and edit if they please..

what i want however is for a user to create their own template, or make edits to an existing one, and save it to be able to come back at a later date.. I think it is possible to save it to my database, I have a template table setup correctly with foreign keys etc and i have the 'templatestyle' field type set as 'blob', in order to save the content here..

I am able to get the contents of the wysiwyg as when I test out this code of clicking the saveContent button I get the current content in the console.log;

```js
$("#saveContent").click(function(){
console.log($("#trumbowyg-demo").html());

});
```

so what i need is this content saved to my database template table which has 3 columns; 'an id, a foreign key id for the user, and the template style..

I realise there is a lot in here and any code provided in order to help me set this up to save my database will be massively appreciated

thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? what you are asking for is really basic.

Comment: i never used this RTE (rich text editor), but to be sure, the template you mean is the [script plugin as shown in the docs](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation/plugins/#plugin-template) or just a plain html template?

Comment: what do you mean by basic? too broad or not specific enough?.. im inexperienced with codeigniter so apologies ..and the template i mean is the current content that sits in the editor.. the editior id is #trumbowyg-demo.. i would like to get the current content that sits there and save it to my db

Comment: so no to answer your question, i am not using the script plugin in the docs, i am using my own plain html template

Comment: what exactly are you having issues with? just save the contents of the editor to a regular `text` field. Blob imo is only suitable for large text files (pdf word) or images, you just will have max a couple hundred lines of  plaintext html code.

Comment: @Alex i suppose im having issues with the actual syntax/code of how to pass the content through the jquery function and to the database

Comment: Does you console log yield everything in the text box? If so then it's just a matter of a simple ajax post and a simple post variable and database insert on the back end.

Comment: @Alex could you please help me out with how to do it? eg code.. and yes it does yield everything in the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you just have to send a simple post with one var to a controller method that receives the post var and inputs it in the database.

JS:

```
$("#saveContent").click(function () {
    var content = $("#trumbowyg-demo").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/somecontroller/add',
        data: {
            content: content
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'error') {
                alert('An error occured: ' + data.msg);
            } else {
                alert('Success: ' + data.msg)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
class Somecontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function add() {

        $content = $this->input->post('content');

        if (empty($content)) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Content field cannot be empty!'));
            exit;
        }

        // db functions should be move to a model
        // probably would be a good idea to filter $content somehow
        // all the db insert does is escape
        $this->db->insert('sometable', array('somefield' => $content));

        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Item added with id: ' . $this->db->insert_id()));
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: cant say this has got it working yet, but theres no errors and its definitely put me on the right track, thank you very much

Comment: without knowing more this is literally a shot in the dark. if you feel this answer has helped you an upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: i have indeed upvoted it, what more do you think i would need to provide in order to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: A detailed statement of the issue you are experiencing and a database schema, ultimately depends on the issue however.